# Spotify metadata through DBUS with track_notifications disabled

Tags: dbus, spotify

**Situation:**

I've got Ubuntu 14.04, Awesome WM and Spotify Linux Client Version: 0.9.11.27

Custom preference setting: `ui.track_notifications_enabled=false` in `/home/USER/.config/spotify/Users/USER/prefs`

(If I don't do this, Spotify will freeze for 5/10 seconds after changing a song, it's unbearable.)

**Problem:**

I'm trying to build my own notification bar which shouldn't be so difficult.

You can get your media info with dbus using:

```
dbus-send --print-reply --session \
          --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify \
          /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 \
          org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get \
          string:'org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player' \
          string:'Metadata'
```

Only problem is, because I have my track_notifications disabled, it will only return an empty array.

```
method return sender=:1.0 -> dest=:1.8 reply_serial=2
    variant       array [
       ]
```

Does anyone know anything (at all) about this? Perhaps a workaround? Or some other way I could get my spotify metadata with this setting disabled?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: May be you are just looking for a work around. But the correct way is to report a bug in first place for that freeze issue.  Another thing, Spotify is a non-free software, we don't have source, so we are somehow limited.

Comment: Concerning the freezze issue, i see 2 new releases in the repo, could you try them [`0.9.17.1`](http://repository-origin.spotify.com/pool/non-free/s/spotify/) & [`1.0.14.124`](http://repository-origin.spotify.com/pool/non-free/s/spotify-client/).

Comment: I will try them as soon as I can, did not realize the 1.0 version did actually come out earlier this month. Every 0.9 version (including 0.9.17.1) did not work. The bug has been reported in the Spotify forums as well, but no results thus far.

Comment: ll, a couple of tries later and It actually works! Put a bounty out just at the right time, with 1.0 coming out just a week before. It fixed everything. Thanks for pointing the repo out, it wouldn't have updates itself.

Comment: Steyn , found that package belong to a `testing`  repository  where its site  just mentions the stable one. I put it as an answer. So it may help any one coming this later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Spotify has two repositories available *stable* and *testing*. See http://repository-origin.spotify.com/dists/

  From the OP comment above, the testing package resolved the freeze bug. Hence no need to disable track notification:

  ```
  ui.track_notifications_enabled=false
  ```

  in `~/.config/spotify/Users/USER/prefs`
- While the OP install it manually from: http://repository-origin.spotify.com/pool/non-free/s/spotify-client/. Here the formal method:

  1. Add the Spotify repository signing key to be able to verify downloaded packages

     ```
     sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys D2C19886
     ```
  2. Add the Spotify repository

     ```
     echo deb http://repository.spotify.com testing non-free | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list
     ```
  3. Update list of available packages

     ```
     sudo apt-get update
     ```
  4. Install Spotify

     ```
     sudo apt-get install spotify-client
     ```

  **Reference:** Same instruction explained here in [Spotify for Linux](https://www.spotify.com/int/download/linux/), just replacing `stable` with `testing`